# How can I insert functions into relay commands?

Tags: c#, lambda, typechecking

I have created something similar to the default RelayCommand implementation. It accepts:

```
public RelayCommand(
    Action executeMethod,
    Func<bool> canExecuteMethod,
)
```

Now suppose I write a command that takes a property and turns it into a bool. Suppose:

```
public Boolean Active { get; set;}
```

and

```
Func<Boolean, Boolean> checkProperty = x => x;
```

Now I wonder why this fails with type checking?

```
RelayCommand(somethingunrelated, checkProperty(Active));
```

Thanks!

Comment: In Haskell if I have a function that is `Func<Boolean, Boolean>` and I put a `Boolean` into it, it becomes `Func<Boolean>`. Why after accepting an argument does it think it is still `Func<Boolean, Boolean>`?

Comment: I did not understand this. May be post as a separate question or elaborate further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining a `Func` with one input `bool` value return bool.

```
Func<Boolean, Boolean> checkProperty
```

But your `RelayCommand` contructor takes a Func delegate which has no input parameter. Only return value of type bool. Change it to this:

```
public RelayCommand(
    Action executeMethod,
    Func<bool,bool> canExecuteMethod,
)
```

EDIT:

As suggest by Alex Joukovsky, use `Predicate<bool>` which has better semantics. See [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public RelayCommand(
        Action executeMethod,
        Predicate<bool> canExecuteMethod,
    )
```

Comment: I suggest to use `Predicate<bool>` instead of `Func<bool, bool>`

Answer (score 0):

Your function must be like

```
bool checkProperty()
{
    return Actcive;
}
```

Then you can use

```
RelayCommand(somethingunrelated, checkProperty);
```